# JSF, Richfaces: How to run Javascript method each time rich:datatable (re)renders?

Tags: java, javascript, events, jsf, richfaces

I have a rich:datatable which may be reRendered my multiple components in my page.

I want to run a Javascript method each time it is rendered, including the first time the page loads.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can call the function on `oncomplete` of each of the components that reRender the datatable
- the initial call is jsf-agnostic - just place the call at the end of the document, or `window.onload = function() {..}`